# How to snap to next ListView item when scrolling to half of it?

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` with items whose height is the size of device's height.

I need the effect similar to `ViewPager` e.g. when I scroll and reach half of the next item, and then I release the finger, the screen has to snap to the next view, not stay on the same position where the finger was released.

Anyone can help me? On the first place, I need to know, how this effect is called so that I can find its implementation on the net.

Thanks!

Comment: @Axarydax You may be right indeed. I will check up this code and delete this thread if that is what I am looking for. Thanks!!!

Comment: @sandalone: If it's a duplicate, you shouldn't delete this question. It'll get closed as duplicate, which just means it'll act like a symlink to the other question. Having your question around can help other people using the same search terms.